# how to use maven (eclipse keppler) on imported non-maven projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have existing projects that I wrote using Eclipse Juno on another machine, on that machine I downloaded the jars I needed (selenium, jxl, sqlite etc.) from the internet manually and then edited the build path to point to them.  I need to move these projects over to a different machine which has Eclipse Kepler loaded.  I thought I'd use maven to link everything up (with a view to retro-fitting the machine with Juno to use maven) so that as I jump between the two machines everything will be kept in order automatically.

I installed maven from the marketplace and ran the install:install-file command, but it won't run the program as it insists the jars it's looking for aren't installed (which of course they aren't, that's what I thought maven did).

Is it not possible to use maven in this way (get it to download and link up missing jars) for an existing project?  Do I need to do it manually, and if so will I have created problems that I'll have to unpick by having tried this with maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [m2e plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/), you can turn on Maven dependency resolution by just right-clicking on the project and choosing Configure->Convert to Maven project. Make sure your project has a valid `pom.xml` file and set everything up properly in Preferences->Maven (proxy, user settings, maven installation, ...)

[image]

If you're not using m2e, you can use the `eclipse` maven plugin like this:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

This will call the [`eclipse` goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html) of the `eclipse` plugin, and it will generate `.project` and `.classpath` files for you with all dependencies pointing to your Maven local repository.

As a side note, the [`install:install-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) goal doesn't have anything to do with what you want to achieve, it's used to install an artifact (a `.jar` file) to your local Maven repository.

Comment: Wonderful, Thank you, I'm going to try it just as soon as I'm sure I have the things you mentioned set up.  if I have a valid pom file, will that be somewhere in the project directories?

Comment: The `pom.xml` file should be in the root directory of the project (i.e. sitting in the same directory `.project` and `.classpath` are)

Comment: OK, I ran the 'convert to maven project' and it created a POM file.  how do I make it download the jars now?

Comment: You should add the `<dependency>` elements in your POM that satisfy the required dependencies for your project. You can add them to the `pom.xml` file manually with a text editor, or use the `m2e` _pom editor_ editor to edit the XML with a form-like GUI in Eclipse, or even right-clicking the project, Maven->Add dependency. For instance, [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp) is the dependency you need to specify for Selenium jars.

Comment: I did the 'add dependency' and then put in the name of jar and picked the one that matched the existing import statement in my code. Thank you very much.